# 404 - Umbraco + Castle Windsor

Tags: c#, umbraco, castle-windsor

Getting a 404 on every request using Umbraco 7.1.8 and Castle Windsor 3.3.0. Fairly new to using Umbraco and have yet to setup IoC with it, however Windsor is not new to me.

The controllers themselves appear to be resolved from the container, and the container itself has the correct (non-umbraco) controllers registered.

What am I missing here? Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

```
public class Global : UmbracoApplication
{

    private static IWindsorContainer container;

    protected override void OnApplicationStarting(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnApplicationStarting(sender, e);

        container = new WindsorContainer().Install(FromAssembly.This());

        UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory.Kernel = container.Kernel;

        FilteredControllerFactoriesResolver.Current.InsertType<UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory>(0);

    }
```

Windsor Controller factory

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected readonly IKernel Kernel;

    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        this.Kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        this.Kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controllerType = GetControllerType(requestContext, controllerName);
        return (IController)this.Kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Filtered Factory

```
public class UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory : WindsorControllerFactory, IFilteredControllerFactory
{

    private static IKernel _kernel;

     public UmbracoFilteredControllerFactory()
        : base(_kernel)
    {
    }

    public static IKernel Kernel
    {
        get
        {
            if (_kernel == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("Set Kernel in WindsorControllerFactory.");
            }
            return _kernel;
        }
        set
        {
            _kernel = value;
        }
    }

    public bool CanHandle(RequestContext request)
    {
        var controllerType = GetControllerType(request, request.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString());

        return Kernel.HasComponent(controllerType);
    }
}
```

Comment: Google reveals this, hope that helps: 
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/developers/api-questions/43497-Umbraco-6-and-Dependancy-Injection

Comment: @sebastiaan Thanks, I had seen that before unfortunately - as of yet unable to get this playing ball. Implemented similar functionality using Ninject and just using a Dependency Resolver - as that answer implies - however I'd rather use a ControllerFactory if possible.